# Hadoop S3 access - FileSystem vs FileContext

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm having trouble accessing the S3 "file-system" from the HDFS FileContext object, but I can use the FileSystem object to do the same.
As I understand, **FileContext** has superseded **FileSystem** so it seems I'm doing it wrong if I need to fall back to using the **FileSystem**.
Am I doing it wrong?  Or is the FileContext not as functional as the older FileSystem?

My functions (FYI - I'm running this from Jupyter, using spark 2.1 with hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.5.1):

```
val hdfsConf = spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration  
import _root_.org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import _root_.org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileContext, Path, FileSystem}

def pathExistsFs(bucket:String, pStr:String): Boolean = {
  val p = new Path(pStr)
  val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(s"s3a://$bucket"), spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  fs.exists(p)  
}

def pathExistsFc(bucket:String, pStr:String): Boolean = {
  val p = new Path(pStr)
  val fc = FileContext.getFileContext(new URI(s"s3a://$bucket"), 
  spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  fc.util().exists(p)
}
```

The output (*pathExistsFs* works, *pathExistsFc* fails):

```
pathExistsF("myBucket", "myS3Key/path.txt") 
>>> res36_5: Boolean = true


pathExistsFc("myBucket", "myS3Key/path.txt") 
>>> org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3a...


org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No AbstractFileSystem for scheme: s3a
org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.createFileSystem(AbstractFileSystem.java:154)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.get(AbstractFileSystem.java:242)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:337)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$2.run(FileContext.java:334)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:334)
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getFileContext(FileContext.java:451)
$sess.cmd37Wrapper$Helper$Hadoop$.pathExistsFc(cmd37.sc:14)
$sess.cmd42Wrapper$Helper.<init>(cmd42.sc:8)
$sess.cmd42Wrapper.<init>(cmd42.sc:686)
$sess.cmd42$.<init>(cmd42.sc:545)
$sess.cmd42$.<clinit>(cmd42.sc:-1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay with the FileSystem APIs; because of it's low-level nature, it's actually where most of the S3 performance dev goes. There is now a bridge class from FileContext to the S3AFileSystem class, but that clearly isn't in your CDH version.

Comment: So when should I use the newer FileContext?  ... I hate have to mentally flip between similar classes.  But keeping track of closing the FileSystem instances is always a pain.  Should I worry about closing a FileSystem?

Comment: if you are asking for filesystems from the cache, don't worry too much about closing them. If you use newInstance, close when you are done. (Note: if you have some service fielding requests from users, you do need to get rid of the filesystems after fielding the request with FileSystem.closeAllForUGI

Comment: Thanks, sounds like I'll stick with the old FileSystem.  Seems the FileContext is a nice idea for an upgrade that didn't quite cross the finish line.

Comment: Two issues: 1. it wasn't backported to Hadoop 1, so held back its adoption and 2. the bridge from FileContext to FileSystem is so good there's no need for implementations to commit to being FileContext only.